# I have issue with contactform7 , when I have submit the form its show green http://prntscr.com/p7l777 , but I don't got any mail

Tags: wordpress, forms

I have an issue with contactform7. When I have submitted the form its show green http://prntscr.com/p7l777, but I don't got any mail.

My contact form code is below :

```html
    <div class="form-main-con">
        <div class="form-title-main">
           <h2>ORDER FORM <h2>
        </div>
        <!-- product-1-start -->
        <div class="product-1">
          <div class="w3-row w3-container">
          <div class="w3-col s3">
            <h5 class="field-title">Product/Style Name:</h5> 
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s9">
            [text style-name id:style-name class:cpt-form-field  placeholder "eg; Staple Tee"]
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-row w3-container">
          <div class="w3-col s3">
            <h5 class="field-title">Product/Style Colour:</h5> 
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s9">
            [text color-name id:style-color class:cpt-form-field  ]
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-row w3-container">
          <div class="w3-col s3">
            <h5 class="field-title">Sizing & Quantities:</h5>
            <p class="field-title-description">(where sizing does not apply
                please just enter total qty below.
                eg; caps, bags, USBs)</p>
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s9">
              <div class="w3-col s1 w3-center" id="form-group">
                 <h5 class="field-size">XS</h5>
                 [text XL id:XS class:cloth-size] 
              </div>
             <div class="w3-col s1 w3-center"id="form-group">
                 <h5 class="field-size">S</h5>
                  [text XL id:S class:cloth-size] 
             </div>
             <div class="w3-col s1 w3-center"id="form-group">
                 <h5 class="field-size">M</h5>
                 [text XL id:M class:cloth-size] 
             </div>
             <div class="w3-col s1 w3-center"id="form-group">
                 <h5 class="field-size">L</h5>
                [text XL id:L class:cloth-size] 
             </div>
             <div class="w3-col s1 w3-center"id="form-group">
                 <h5 class="field-size">XL</h5>
                [text XL id:XL class:cloth-size] 
             </div>
             <div class="w3-col s1"id="form-group">
                 <h5 class="field-size">2XL</h5>
                 [text XL id:2XL class:cloth-size] 
             </div>

             <div class="w3-col s1"id="form-group">
                 <h5 class="field-size">3XL</h5>
                 [text XL id:3XL class:cloth-size] 
             </div>
          </div>

        </div>

             <div class="w3-row w3-container">
              <div class="w3-col s3">
            <h5 class="field-title">The total Order</h5> 
              </div>
              <div class="w3-col s8" id="form-group">
             [number TotalAmount id:total-amount]
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-row w3-container">
          <div class="w3-col s3">
            <h5 class="field-title">Other Sizing Description:</h5> 
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s9">
            [text size-descrip id:size-descrip class:cpt-form-field placeholder "eg; 4GB USB"]
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-row w3-container">
          <div class="w3-col s3">

            <h5 class="field-title">Total Quantity:</h5> 
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s9">
            [text t-quantity id:t-quantity class:cpt-form-field  ]
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-row w3-container">
          <div class="w3-col s3">
            <h5 class="field-upload-title">Upload Artwork/Data:</h5>
            <p class="field-title-description">Click <a >HERE</a> to learn about
            the artwork specifications
            we require. </p>
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s9">
            <div class="image-upload">
             <label for="file-input">
                <img src="#"/>
             </label>
             [file art-work limit:2000000 id:file-input]
             <p class="field-upload-description">Sending multiple files over 2MB?
                please use a free file sharing website such as :https://wetransfer.com/ </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
         <p class="Add-product-2 btn-style"><a >+ Add Another Product</a><p>
        </div>
        <!-- product-1-end -->

        <!-- product-2-start -->
        <div class="product-2">
          <div class="w3-row w3-container">
          <div class="w3-col s3">
            <h5 class="field-title">Product/Style Name:</h5> 
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s9">
            [text style-name id:style-name class:cpt-form-field  placeholder "eg; Staple Tee"]
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-row w3-container">
          <div class="w3-col s3">
            <h5 class="field-title">Product/Style Colour:</h5> 
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s9">
            [text color-name id:style-color class:cpt-form-field  ]
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-row w3-container">
          <div class="w3-col s3">
            <h5 class="field-title">Sizing & Quantities:</h5>
            <p class="field-title-description">(where sizing does not apply
                please just enter total qty below.
                eg; caps, bags, USBs)</p>
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s9">
              <div class="w3-col s1 w3-center" id="form-group">
                 <h5 class="field-size">XS</h5>
                 [text XL id:XS class:cloth-size] 
              </div>
             <div class="w3-col s1 w3-center"id="form-group">
                 <h5 class="field-size">S</h5>
                  [text XL id:S class:cloth-size] 
             </div>
             <div class="w3-col s1 w3-center"id="form-group">
                 <h5 class="field-size">M</h5>
                 [text XL id:M class:cloth-size] 
             </div>
             <div class="w3-col s1 w3-center"id="form-group">
                 <h5 class="field-size">L</h5>
                [text XL id:L class:cloth-size] 
             </div>
             <div class="w3-col s1 w3-center"id="form-group">
                 <h5 class="field-size">XL</h5>
                [text XL id:XL class:cloth-size] 
             </div>
             <div class="w3-col s1"id="form-group">
                 <h5 class="field-size">2XL</h5>
                 [text XL id:2XL class:cloth-size] 
             </div>

             <div class="w3-col s1"id="form-group">
                 <h5 class="field-size">3XL</h5>
                 [text XL id:3XL class:cloth-size] 
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-row w3-container">
          <div class="w3-col s3">
            <h5 class="field-title">Other Sizing Description:</h5> 
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s9">
            [text size-descrip id:size-descrip class:cpt-form-field placeholder "eg; 4GB USB"]
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-row w3-container">
          <div class="w3-col s3">
            <h5 class="field-title">Total Quantity:</h5> 
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s9">
            [text t-quantity id:t-quantity class:cpt-form-field  ]
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-row w3-container">
          <div class="w3-col s3">
            <h5 class="field-upload-title">Upload Artwork/Data:</h5>
            <p class="field-title-description">Click <a >HERE</a> to learn about
            the artwork specifications
            we require. </p>
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s9">
            <div class="image-upload">
             <label for="file-input">
                <img src="#"/>
             </label>
             [file art-work limit:2000000 id:file-input]
             <p class="field-upload-description">Sending multiple files over 2MB?
                please use a free file sharing website such as :https://wetransfer.com/ </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
         <p class="Add-product-3 btn-style"><a >+ Add Another Product</a><p>
        </div>
        <!-- product-2-end -->

        <!-- product-3-start -->
        <div class="product-3">
          <div class="w3-row w3-container">
          <div class="w3-col s3">
            <h5 class="field-title">Product/Style Name:</h5> 
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s9">
            [text style-name id:style-name class:cpt-form-field  placeholder "eg; Staple Tee"]
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-row w3-container">
          <div class="w3-col s3">
            <h5 class="field-title">Product/Style Colour:</h5> 
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s9">
            [text color-name id:style-color class:cpt-form-field  ]
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-row w3-container">
          <div class="w3-col s3">
            <h5 class="field-title">Sizing & Quantities:</h5>
            <p class="field-title-description">(where sizing does not apply
                please just enter total qty below.
                eg; caps, bags, USBs)</p>
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s9">
              <div class="w3-col s1 w3-center" id="form-group">
                 <h5 class="field-size">XS</h5>
                 [text XL id:XS class:cloth-size] 
              </div>
             <div class="w3-col s1 w3-center"id="form-group">
                 <h5 class="field-size">S</h5>
                  [text XL id:S class:cloth-size] 
             </div>
             <div class="w3-col s1 w3-center"id="form-group">
                 <h5 class="field-size">M</h5>
                 [text XL id:M class:cloth-size] 
             </div>
             <div class="w3-col s1 w3-center"id="form-group">
                 <h5 class="field-size">L</h5>
                [text XL id:L class:cloth-size] 
             </div>
             <div class="w3-col s1 w3-center"id="form-group">
                 <h5 class="field-size">XL</h5>
                [text XL id:XL class:cloth-size] 
             </div>
             <div class="w3-col s1"id="form-group">
                 <h5 class="field-size">2XL</h5>
                 [text XL id:2XL class:cloth-size] 
             </div>

             <div class="w3-col s1"id="form-group">
                 <h5 class="field-size">3XL</h5>
                 [text XL id:3XL class:cloth-size] 
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-row w3-container">
          <div class="w3-col s3">
            <h5 class="field-title">Other Sizing Description:</h5> 
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s9">
            [text size-descrip id:size-descrip class:cpt-form-field placeholder "eg; 4GB USB"]
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-row w3-container">
          <div class="w3-col s3">
            <h5 class="field-title">Total Quantity:</h5> 
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s9">
            [text t-quantity id:t-quantity class:cpt-form-field  ]
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-row w3-container">
          <div class="w3-col s3">
            <h5 class="field-upload-title">Upload Artwork/Data:</h5>
            <p class="field-title-description">Click <a >HERE</a> to learn about
            the artwork specifications
            we require. </p>
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s9">
            <div class="image-upload">
             <label for="file-input">
                <img src="#"/>
             </label>
             [file art-work limit:2000000 id:file-input]
             <p class="field-upload-description">Sending multiple files over 2MB?
                please use a free file sharing website such as :https://wetransfer.com/ </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
         <p class="Add-product-4 btn-style"><a >+ Add Another Product</a><p>
        </div>
        <!-- product-3-end -->

        <!-- product-4-start -->
        <div class="product-4">
          <div class="w3-row w3-container">
          <div class="w3-col s3">
            <h5 class="field-title">Product/Style Name:</h5> 
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s9">
            [text style-name id:style-name class:cpt-form-field  placeholder "eg; Staple Tee"]
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-row w3-container">
          <div class="w3-col s3">
            <h5 class="field-title">Product/Style Colour:</h5> 
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s9">
            [text color-name id:style-color class:cpt-form-field  ]
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-row w3-container">
          <div class="w3-col s3">
            <h5 class="field-title">Sizing & Quantities:</h5>
            <p class="field-title-description">(where sizing does not apply
                please just enter total qty below.
                eg; caps, bags, USBs)</p>
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s9">
              <div class="w3-col s1 w3-center" id="form-group">
                 <h5 class="field-size">XS</h5>
                 [text XL id:XS class:cloth-size] 
              </div>
             <div class="w3-col s1 w3-center"id="form-group">
                 <h5 class="field-size">S</h5>
                  [text XL id:S class:cloth-size] 
             </div>
             <div class="w3-col s1 w3-center"id="form-group">
                 <h5 class="field-size">M</h5>
                 [text XL id:M class:cloth-size] 
             </div>
             <div class="w3-col s1 w3-center"id="form-group">
                 <h5 class="field-size">L</h5>
                [text XL id:L class:cloth-size] 
             </div>
             <div class="w3-col s1 w3-center"id="form-group">
                 <h5 class="field-size">XL</h5>
                [text XL id:XL class:cloth-size] 
             </div>
             <div class="w3-col s1"id="form-group">
                 <h5 class="field-size">2XL</h5>
                 [text XL id:2XL class:cloth-size] 
             </div>

             <div class="w3-col s1"id="form-group">
                 <h5 class="field-size">3XL</h5>
                 [text XL id:3XL class:cloth-size] 
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-row w3-container">
          <div class="w3-col s3">
            <h5 class="field-title">Other Sizing Description:</h5> 
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s9">
            [text size-descrip id:size-descrip class:cpt-form-field placeholder "eg; 4GB USB"]
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-row w3-container">
          <div class="w3-col s3">
            <h5 class="field-title">Total Quantity:</h5> 
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s9">
            [text t-quantity id:t-quantity class:cpt-form-field  ]
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-row w3-container">
          <div class="w3-col s3">
            <h5 class="field-upload-title">Upload Artwork/Data:</h5>
            <p class="field-title-description">Click <a >HERE</a> to learn about
            the artwork specifications
            we require. </p>
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s9">
            <div class="image-upload">
             <label for="file-input">
                <img src="#"/>
             </label>
             [file art-work limit:2000000 id:file-input]
             <p class="field-upload-description">Sending multiple files over 2MB?
                please use a free file sharing website such as :https://wetransfer.com/ </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
         <p class="Add-product-5 btn-style"><a >+ Add Another Product</a><p>
        </div>
        <!-- product-4-end -->

        <!-- product-5-start -->
        <div class="product-5">
          <div class="w3-row w3-container">
          <div class="w3-col s3">
            <h5 class="field-title">Product/Style Name:</h5> 
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s9">
            [text style-name id:style-name class:cpt-form-field  placeholder "eg; Staple Tee"]
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-row w3-container">
          <div class="w3-col s3">
            <h5 class="field-title">Product/Style Colour:</h5> 
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s9">
            [text color-name id:style-color class:cpt-form-field  ]
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-row w3-container">
          <div class="w3-col s3">
            <h5 class="field-title">Sizing & Quantities:</h5>
            <p class="field-title-description">(where sizing does not apply
                please just enter total qty below.
                eg; caps, bags, USBs)</p>
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s9">
              <div class="w3-col s1 w3-center" id="form-group">
                 <h5 class="field-size">XS</h5>
                 [text XL id:XS class:cloth-size] 
              </div>
             <div class="w3-col s1 w3-center"id="form-group">
                 <h5 class="field-size">S</h5>
                  [text XL id:S class:cloth-size] 
             </div>
             <div class="w3-col s1 w3-center"id="form-group">
                 <h5 class="field-size">M</h5>
                 [text XL id:M class:cloth-size] 
             </div>
             <div class="w3-col s1 w3-center"id="form-group">
                 <h5 class="field-size">L</h5>
                [text XL id:L class:cloth-size] 
             </div>
             <div class="w3-col s1 w3-center"id="form-group">
                 <h5 class="field-size">XL</h5>
                [text XL id:XL class:cloth-size] 
             </div>
             <div class="w3-col s1"id="form-group">
                 <h5 class="field-size">2XL</h5>
                 [text XL id:2XL class:cloth-size] 
             </div>

             <div class="w3-col s1"id="form-group">
                 <h5 class="field-size">3XL</h5>
                 [text XL id:3XL class:cloth-size] 
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-row w3-container">
          <div class="w3-col s3">
            <h5 class="field-title">Other Sizing Description:</h5> 
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s9">
            [text size-descrip id:size-descrip class:cpt-form-field placeholder "eg; 4GB USB"]
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-row w3-container">
          <div class="w3-col s3">
            <h5 class="field-title">Total Quantity:</h5> 
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s9">
            [text t-quantity id:t-quantity class:cpt-form-field  ]
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-row w3-container">
          <div class="w3-col s3">
            <h5 class="field-upload-title">Upload Artwork/Data:</h5>
            <p class="field-title-description">Click <a >HERE</a> to learn about
            the artwork specifications
            we require. </p>
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s9">
            <div class="image-upload">
             <label for="file-input">
                <img src="#"/>
             </label>
             [file art-work limit:2000000 id:file-input]
             <p class="field-upload-description">Sending multiple files over 2MB?
                please use a free file sharing website such as :https://wetransfer.com/ </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
         <!-- <p class="Add-product-2 btn-style"><a >+ Add Another Product</a><p> -->
        </div>
        <!-- product-5-end -->

        <!-- delivery data -->
        <div class="w3-row w3-container">
          <div class="w3-col s3">
            <h5 class="field-title">Delivery Address:</h5> 
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s9">
            [text c-name id:c-name class:cpt-form-field placeholder "Company Name"]
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-row w3-container">
          <div class="w3-col s3">
            <p class="field-title-description">(we do not ship to PO Boxes
        and do not offer pick up from
        our warehouse)</p> 
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s9">
            [textarea physical-address id:physical-address class:cpt-text-area placeholder "Physical Address"]
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-row w3-container">
          <div class="w3-col s3">
            <h5 class="field-title">Desired Delivery Date:</h5> 
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s9">
            [date delivery-date id:delivery-date class:cpt-form-field]
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-row w3-container">
          <div class="w3-col s3">
            <h5 class="field-title">Shipping Notes:</h5> 
          </div>
          <div class="w3-col s9">
            [text s-notes id:s-notes class:cpt-form-field placeholder "eg; please deliver before 3pm as we close"]
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="w3-row w3-container text-center" style="margin-top: 30px;">
         [submit id:sub class:sub "SUBMIT"]
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my [mail configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7WWJ.png).

How can I solve this ? How can I fix this? It's most important for me.

Answer (score 1):

For troubleshooting email issue we have to consider few things in mind as listed below:

1. Check your junk or spam folder, receiving email can also take some time depending on you server.
2. Try changing you email address and add gmail email to make sure if is not cause by email address or email server.If this seems to be reason for issue try contacting you hosting provider.
3. You contact form 7 plugin may not installed correctly try removing and re-configuring  plugin if solved issue.
4. Check does your wordpress send email or not.This can be checked by many free available plugin or you can also create a custom function with wp_mail() and mail().
5. If your wordpress does not send email don't worry there are many ways to sort out this.First it to configure a SMTP plugin, configuring this plugin mostly solves problem.
6. [Click here](https://contactform7.com/setting-up-mail/#Contact_Form_7_Email_Issues) to check out Contact form 7 email issue documentation.
7. At last generate a ticket and contact your hosting provider company regarding issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure your SMTP at all?
Without, you´re not able to send any mails out of WordPress.

You can do it the easy way with a plugin like for example *WP Mail SMTP* that configures the wp_mail() function.